# finding supremum of a function

Tags: real-analysis

I have the following function:

$f := (0,1)\rightarrow \mathbb{R}; x\rightarrow x(1-x)$

$(0,1)$ is an open interval $(0 < x < 1)$ with $x \in \mathbb{R}$. Now I have to determine the Supremum and Infimum of the image of $f$.
Since the Supremum and Infimum are definite, I would say that the Supremum is $\frac{1}{4}$ and that the Infimum doesn't exist but since our Interval is limited, there should be one.

Note: I am not allowed to use anything related to differentiability.

Answer (score 0):

we have by $AM-GM$ $$\sqrt{x(1-x)}\le \frac{x+1-x}{2}=\frac{1}{2}$$ thus we have $$x(1-x)\le \frac{1}{4}$$ and since $x\in \mathbb{R}$ with $$0<x(1-x)$$ we have $$x(1-x)>0$$